# Ajax Jquery Call for On Submit Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Despite adding the prevent default option on submit, the code is not being redirected to try.php and on submit the values are being displayed on the browser like it does by GET method. I have been on this for hours now. Kindly Help!

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "try.php",
    cache: false,
    type    :"POST",
    data    : {action:'John'},
    success : function( data ) {
    $("#show_here").val(data);     
                      }
           });
       });

    });
```

Comment: Also add your html code

Comment: Did you tried `echo $_POST['action']` In `try.php` page.

Comment: You have another error in your page that's causing your javascript to not fire. Open your console in your web inspector.

Comment: What is the sequence of adding the form and binding this jQuery call?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy

Can you specify the jquery libraries I should use for there? Maybe there is an error there

Comment: format html and add in question

Comment: The version of jQuery wouldn't matter as nothing you've shown above has been introduced or removed in any version since jQuery's inception; this is just a simple AJAX request.

Comment: @NehaAgarwal You want to show your data in input box?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Okay Thanks. Then what could possibly stop this code from working?

Comment: @aldrin27, I need to perform SQL Queries in try.php but I can't proceed unless this works.

Comment: @Neha is this all of the code on the page?No other javascript besides the library its self and this block?

Comment: @NehaAgarwal Do you have included the jquery script file? or bootstrap file?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, You can ask any questions you need to know to figure out what's happening 

I've been on this for very long now

Comment: @aldrin27, You can ask any questions you need to know to figure out what's happening I've been on this for very long now

Comment: @NehaAgarwal I think you are overriding the versions of your jquery s the ajax submit didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works:

```
        $('.please').submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //var act = $("input[name='v_year_name']").val();

          $.ajax({
            url     : "try.php",
            cache: false,
            type    :"POST",
            data    : {action:'John'},
            success : function( data ) {
                     $("#show_here").val(data);     
                     }

          });

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

check entered url/path is correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.ajaxform1').submit( function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            url     : "try.php",
            cache   : false,
            type    :"POST",
            data    : {action:'John'},
            success : function( data ) {
                $("#show_here").val(data);     
            }               
        });
    });     });
```